# Условие с сессией в php

Tags: php

1й скрипт создает сессию и:

```
$_SESSION['role']='admin';
```

2й скрипт использует:

```
if ($_SESSION['role']!='admin' && $_SESSION['role']!='moder') die('нельзя'');
```

Почему-то при сессии выше выводит "нельзя", почему?

Comment: die('нельзя '.$_SESSION['role']); что выведет?

Comment: Забыт, во 2м скрипте)
Все заработало))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`session_start()` не забыли случайно?

Я однажды тоже забыл)) Минут 15 убил, пока не заметил)